# Will this speed up my GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

Will editing the "/etc/default/grub" file, 
`"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash""` to `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash=noop"` or
`"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash=deadline"`

speed through the grub menu on boot?

I found this from:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56_sTH29Fa8

Comment: It's not `splash=noop`, it's `elevator=noop`, watch the video again and look carefully. https://blog.codeship.com/linux-io-scheduler-tuning/ will give you an overview about what this kernel parameter does. It may or may not improve read speed and thus decrease boot time.

Comment: Use `systemd-analyze blame` to see what is taking most time during boot. Tell us how many seconds it takes to boot (15 for me) and what your hardware is (Windows gaming laptop from 2016 purchased 40% off in 2017 for good Linux cost benefit for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That only affects the parameters passed to the Linux kernel, not behavior of grub itself.

From `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`

> ```
> 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT'
>  Unless 'GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY' is set to 'true', two menu entries
>  will be generated for each Linux kernel: one default entry and one
>  entry for recovery mode.  This option lists command-line arguments
>  to add only to the default menu entry, after those listed in
>  'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX'.
> ```